# How to clip a rectangle from a tiff?

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap

I have a Winforms Gui in C# that allows a user to draw a rectangle on a display of a tiff and save the position, height, width etc. 
Basically, what I want to do is take the saved position, height and width of the rectangle and clip that area into a sep. bitmap that can then be passed to sep. method that will just OCR the new clip of the bitmap only.
What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Graphics.DrawImage() to copy the selection portion of the source image.  You'll need [the overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142040.aspx) that takes a source and a destination Rectangle.  Create the Graphics instance from Graphics.FromImage() on a new bitmap that has the same size as the rectangle.

```
    public static Bitmap CropImage(Image source, Rectangle crop) {
        var bmp = new Bitmap(crop.Width, crop.Height);
        using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
            gr.DrawImage(source, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), crop, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
        return bmp;
    }
```

Comment: Also make sure that you're managing your crop rectangle in relative percentages versus absolutes in the event that you're scaling your display of the original image.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Bitmap.Clone()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.clone.aspx) to create a copy of the cropped region.

```
public Bitmap ClipBitmap(Bitmap src, Rectangle crop)
{
  return src.Clone(crop, src.PixelFormat);
}
```